# ERROR InnoDB: Trying to access page number .. in space .., space name..., which is outside the tablespace bounds

Tags: innodb, errors

I am running a mysql database server (5.7) on a virtual ubuntu 16.04 host.

This host collects syslog messages from my other network hosts, adds the values to a pipe and creates mysql records for each forwarded message.

In general this works as expected, but since starting this project it happened twice that my mysql instance dies with the following error:

```
[ERROR] InnoDB: Trying to access page number 208260 in space 70, space name DBNAME/TABLENAME, which is outside the tablespace bounds. Byte offset 0, len 16384, i/o type read. If you get this error at mysqld startup, please check that your my.cnf matches the ibdata files that you have in the MySQL server.
[ERROR] InnoDB: Server exits.
```

I am somehow used to mysql but never realized this particular error on aby of my servers.

At that point i am not able to start the mysql server again without altering the config.

After re-starting the server (using `innodb_force_recovery = 2`) i can connect to the mysql server and switch to the related database.

If i then try to show all tables of this particular db i get:

```
mysql> show tables;
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    3
Current database: syslog-ng

ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
ERROR: 
Can't connect to the server
```

**Questions:**

- what might cause such `outside bounds` issues?
- How can i prevent it from happening again?